# How to change the background color in a custom made splash screen?

Tags: java, android, xml, xamarin.android, splash-screen

In order to remove the default white splash screen I made a custom theme:

**styles.xml**

```
 <style name="AppTheme.SplashTheme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
  </style>
```

**splash_screen.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:opacity="opaque">

<!--<item android:drawable="?colorPrimary" />-->
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/wq_logo" />
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Everything works fine but I want to change the background color of it. Its currently showing a purple color background. I want to make it white.
In this app I'm using a Navigation drawer layout.

Comment: You don't have to apply a separate Theme for the Splash Activity, do you? Just change the background color of the xml file of the Activity would do.

Comment: @vidulaJ in default android shows whitescreen while loading the app. i wanted to remove it and show logo in middle. this is the easiest method i found. and its working fine.

Comment: Yeah, got your point. Good to know it's working!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the `splash_screen.xml` like this

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:opacity="opaque">

<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"      
       android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="@color/grey" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/wq_logo" />
</item>
```

You can add another `item` to the `layer-list`. You only have to change the background color to your preferred one.

Comment: Oh. Thank you very much. its working. i have lot to learn in using XML :)

Comment: @Cade glad to help you. you can accept the answer if it help you. So in future it help other people.

Comment: @Ironman I think you have add color red not grey so correct it.

Answer (score 1):

For my part, this solution did not solve the problem. To fix it I declare the background image of the splash screen like this: (dont use bitmap)

```
<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:gravity="center" />
```